# error: cannot find symbol for correctly used methods (I think)

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I have

```
ExecutorService tpool = new ThreadPoolExecutor(5, 50, 5, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, new SynchronousQueue<>());
```

and later on

```
int y = tpool.getPoolSize();
```

but when I attempt to compile it says error: cannot find symbol

I already tried these imports (I used .concurrent.* originally and threw the second two afterwards):

```
import java.util.concurrent.*; 
import java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;
```

Out of curiosity I also tried

```
boolean x = tpool.isShutdown();
String z = tpool.toString();
long a = tpool.getTaskCount();
int b = tpool.getCorePoolSize();
```

to which only .isShutdown and .getCorepoolSize did not give a compiler error.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: try this: `((ThreadPoolExecutor) tpool).getPoolSize();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want those functionalities, it seems you are looking for :

```
import java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

...

ThreadPoolExecutor tpool = ..
```

and not :

```
ExecutorService tpool = ...
```